# Javafx font derive bold

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, javafx-8

I wanted to change a (loaded) text font dinamically for my javafx application, so I did this code:

```
Font font = Font.loadFont(Fonts.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path/font.woff").toExternalForm(), 25);
Font bold = Font.font(font.getFamily(), FontWeight.BOLD, font.getSize());
Font italic = Font.font(font.getFamily(), FontPosture.ITALIC, font.getSize());
Font boldItalic = Font.font(font.getFamily(), FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, font.getSize());
```

but when I try to change the text font to bold or italic nothing changes, and I don't seem to locate some method like the one in java.awt.Font#deriveFont where you could derive italic or bold from another font.
Code to apply the font:

```
public void applyFont(javafx.scene.text.Text text) {
    text.setFont(font);
}
```

EDIT: More log:
I put some log that says what font is he getting and prints the Font#toString() result:

```
getFont(bold=false, italic=false) -> Font[name=<Name> Regular, family=<Name>, style=Regular, size=25.0]
getFont(bold=true, italic=false) -> Font[name=<Name> Regular, family=<Name>, style=Regular, size=25.0]
getFont(bold=false, italic=true) -> Font[name=<Name> Regular, family=<Name>, style=Regular, size=25.0]
getFont(bold=true, italic=true) -> Font[name=<Name> Regular, family=<Name>, style=Regular, size=25.0]
```

But if I replace the first line of code in the font loading with

```
font = Font.font(null, 25);//get the system's default font
```

It works and I get this output:

```
getFont(bold=false, italic=false) -> Font[name=System Regular, family=System, style=Regular, size=25.0]
getFont(bold=true, italic=false) -> Font[name=System Bold, family=System, style=Bold, size=25.0]
getFont(bold=false, italic=true) -> Font[name=System Italic, family=System, style=Italic, size=25.0]
getFont(bold=true, italic=true) -> Font[name=System Bold Italic, family=System, style=Bold Italic, size=25.0]
```

Comment: Your code to apply the font always seems to use the font as it's loaded from the resource. Why do you expect it to differ?

Comment: That code is only to show how I applied it, in the real application it's this: "text.setFont(Fonts.getFont(bold, italic));" where Fonts.getFont(bool bld, bool itlc) is this: "return bld ? (itlc ? boldItalic : bold) : itlc ? italic : font;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load another font file, that will provide appropriate Posture or Weight.

For every popular font (including System, that is used, when you call `Font.font(null, 25)`) there are several font files in the system: one for regular, one for italic, one for bold etc.

For instance, for Times New Roman there are four files in my Fonts folder:

- Times New Roman Bold Italic.ttf
- Times New Roman Bold.ttf
- Times New Roman Italic.ttf
- Times New Roman.ttf