# What's wrong with Java FX's bold handling?

Tags: javafx

Getting a bold label in JavaFX should be as simple as:

```
<Label text="Some bold text" style='-fx-font-weight: bold'/>
```

but it seems it is not.

Looking thru some Q&A in stackoverflow i found:

- [Javafx font derive bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703932/javafx-font-derive-bold)
- [FXML Label text bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49813907/fxml-label-text-bold/49824541)
- [Using Arial Unicode MS BOLD in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56731762/using-arial-unicode-ms-bold-in-javafx)
- [Java FX: Bold and Italic styles are not getting applied for some of the font families](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49042348/java-fx-bold-and-italic-styles-are-not-getting-applied-for-some-of-the-font-fam/49042883#49042883)

which show that people get mixed mileage. There are a few thousand views on most of these questions but only a few upvotes and comments with mixed results. In some contexts things seem to run fine in others not at all. Unfortunately i am on the "not at all" side on my Mac OS High Sierra with

```
java version "1.8.0_152"
```

So i wonder what the reason is that things do not work "out of the box" and whether there is a valid platform independent work-around or we just have to put up with this unhappy situation.

Comment: For a workaround https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409438/1497139 seems to help I am using .root{
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bugs:

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8185569
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8176835
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8222624

to work around it set a default font that supports bold in your css e.g.

```
.root{
    -fx-font-size: 14pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Arial";
}
```